# Can I plug a driver/transformer for 12v undercabinet lighting into the same outlet the OTR microwave is plugged into?

Tags: electrical

I have an outlet in the cabinet above the microwave that the microwave is plugged into.

I'd like to  use the same outlet to plug in the driver/transformer for 12v under-cabinet lighting but am not sure if I can do this by code.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: If it's a regular plug, it should be fine, it just so happens to be being used for a microwave as well. If it's not a regular plug, then no, you'll likely need a different circuit.

Comment: What else shares the circuit the microwave's on? How many watts is the microwave rated for?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, if an appliance is supposed to be on a dedicated *circuit*, then it will either have a single receptacle instead of a double receptacle or it will be hard-wired. So if the original stuff was installed correctly (not always the case, but we'll assume that is the situation) then any place you see an empty receptacle should be safe to plug in a small load.

From a *practical* situation, 12V undercabinet lighting likely uses very little power, and a microwave is typically used at high power only for short intervals, so the risk of an overloaded circuit is very low.

What I would **not** do is plug in a toaster oven or other high wattage appliance into that receptacle, because if you used it at the same time as the microwave then you could trip a breaker.